# Is there a way to know if a Sharepoint 2013 farm was upgraded from earlier versions

Tags: 2013, administration, upgrade, server-farm, farm

We are working on a new project with one of our customers, and they have on-premise SharePoint server 2013 with SP1 and January 2016 cumulative update installed. But i am trying to know the history of this SharePoint farm, and if it was upgraded from earlier versions of SharePoint such as 2010 or 2007, or it is a SharePoint 2013 from day one.

now our customer do not have the answer,, so not sure if there is a way to know if this SharePoint 2013 server is 2013 from day one or it is upgraded from 2010 or from 2007 ?
Thanks

**EDIT**

now i run the following command, on our web application's content database, and i got the following  :-
[image]

now as shown above all the versions starts with 15, so does this mean that it is a 2013 database from day one ? second question i can not find any version which represents the following number `15.0.13.0` what does this represents ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The farm couldn't have been 'upgraded', but the databases certainly could have. For the Content Databases, you can run the following T-SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM Versions (NoLock)`

That will tell you the version history in the `Version` column.

Comment: can you check my edit to the original question, i run the command as mentioned on your reply..

Comment: Looks like 2013 only to me.

Comment: but do you have any idea on what does this farm build number represents 15.0.13.0 ??

Comment: SharePoint 2013.